# Wait for text change in td with protractor

Tags: angular, selenium, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I have table with `sortable columns` and when sort column is clicked I need to wait for sorting done, to detect data change in table I'm trying to save current text from `td` in variable and then compare in `browser.wait` to new text of first `td`

```
waitForTDValueChange(currentValue: string, index: number): void {
     browser.wait(
         () => element.all(by.css('td[data-header="HEADERNAME"]'))
         .get(index)
         .getText()
         .then((txt) => {
             return txt !== currentValue;
         }), 30000);
}
```

here's my code but it throws `Stale Element Reference Exception`..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [locator `cssContainingText()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText) together with [Expected Condition `stalenessOf`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf) or a [check for `indexOf !== 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Something like this:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions; 
//or "global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;" in conf.js to have it globally available
waitForTDValueChange = function(currentValue, index){
    var list = element.all(by.css('td[data-header="HEADERNAME"]'));
    var el = element(by.cssContainingText('td[data-header="HEADERNAME"]', currentValue))
    //idea 1 - not sure, if it only works, when el disappears, so position change might not be sufficient
    browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(el), 5000);
    //idea 2 - get index of current element until it's not on index = 0 anymore
    browser.wait(list.indexOf(el) !== 0, 5000);
};
```